# Why are convolutions written with a minus sign

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

The convolution of two function $f$ and $g$ is defined<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition)</sup> as $$(f*g)(x) = \int f(y) g(x-y) dy.$$

Terry Tao [explains very nicely on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5916) that the convolution with a bump function can be thought of as "blurring" the function. There is also a [list of applications of convolutions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Applications).

In these contexts, it appears the bump function used is usually symmetric about the $y$-axis, so it shouldn't matter whether we write $g(x-y)$ or $g(x+y)$. However, I have never seen the convolution defined with a plus sign: $$(f*g)(x) = \int f(y) g(x+y) dy.$$

If the point is to translate a bump function by $x$, then why is it standard to write $g(x-y)$ and not $g(x+y)$? Are there other uses of convolutions where it is important to write $g(x-y)$?

Comment: This question has been asked before -- see answers at [Definition of convolution?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714507/definition-of-convolution)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Wow, I thought I looked, but I guess I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: x @Snow: It is usually best to leave duplicates up, as wayposts to improve searchability. Since you couldn't find the earlier question (and I only could because I remembered answering it myself), someone else might have the same trouble -- and if they then search using the same words that occur to you, they may find this question to lead them on the right way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fantastic. Thank you!